# Custom Github Pages not recognizing assets folder

Tags: javascript, html, github, web-hosting, github-pages

So I've followed the steps outlined [here](https://gist.github.com/cobyism/4730490) in order to host my github pages site from a [subdirectory](https://github.com/ags2121/personal-space-site/tree/gh-pages) of my [repo](https://github.com/ags2121/personal-space-site). You can view the site here: https://ags2121.github.io/personal-space-site

It's working as expected, but for some reason I can't get Github Pages to pick up the assets directory. When I view the page source in a browser it's not there and there are console errors thrown for the referenced assets. Everything else in the subdirectory - the js and css directories and the index.html - is picked up, but not assets. The assets dir is not specified in any .gitignore and is committed to the repo.

Any idea what's going on?

Comment: I can see it: http://imgur.com/eyvwUH1

Comment: Hey thanks for checking it out. I should have specified the url: https://ags2121.github.io/personal-space-site

Comment: the other url points to a heroku build

Comment: is this what you are talking about? http://imgur.com/lGgOBdX

Comment: yeah and if you can view the site sources, you'll notice the 'assets' directory is absent: http://imgur.com/a/Nnq17